# Kingfisher: No such module 'CommonCrypto'

Tags: swift, commoncrypto, kingfisher

I have installed the latest version of `Kingfisher` i.e. `pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.0'`, yet when I try to build my project I am receiving the following compile error:

`No such module 'CommonCrypto' String+MD5.swift`

I have no idea why this error is occurring.

Xcode version: 9.4.1

platform :ios, '10.0'

Comment: make sure you are loading the correct xcode project. When you create and install a pod it creates a NEW xcode project with ending .xcworspace , has a white logo. Open that project and build it.. you should see the errror gone... also you should update to the LATEST version of xcode

Comment: Wasn't CommonCripto more a thing in XCode 10? Isn't Kingfisher 5.0 not stable, and might needs XCode 10 (because of some Swift version ?)

Comment: @JulianSilvestri I am running the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj!! If I was running the xcodeproj I would get an error on the entire kingfisher module, which I am not getting. it's a specific weird error relating to CommonCrypto module within the kingfisher scripts.

Comment: @Larme so You think the error is due to my Xcode version 9?

Answer (score 0):

Kingfisher (5.1.0) throws me that error only with Xcode 9.*, it works fine with Xcode 10.*.

[Error in file String+MD5.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiJDy.png)

Comment: this looks like a comment